# Updating data. Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, pdo

I want to update the login user profile. When i clicked the update button, this error apprear. Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens. May I know why and how to solve it?

This is for updating the users' data

pelanggan_crud.php

```
<?php

include_once 'database.php';

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//Create
if (isset($_POST['create'])) {

  try {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_pelanggan(pelanggan_id, nama_penuh, nama_pengguna, katalaluan, alamat_pelanggan, email_pelanggan, notel_pelanggan, img) VALUES(:pid, :name, :nama, :password,  :alamat, :email, :notel, :img)");

    $stmt->bindParam(':pid', $pid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':nama', $nama, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':alamat', $alamat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':notel', $notel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':img', $img, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $pid = uniqid('P', true);  
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $nama = $_POST['nama'];
    $pass = md5($_POST['password']);
    $repass = md5($_POST['repassword']);
    $alamat = $_POST['alamat'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $notel = $_POST['notel'];
    $img = $_POST['img'];



    if($pass == $repass)   {
    echo "<script>alert('Data anda berjaya direkodkan. Terima kasih. Sila log masuk semula')</script>";     
    $stmt->execute();
     }

    if($pass !== $repass) {
       echo "<script>alert('Pastikan katalaluan dan taip semula katalaluan adalah sama')</script>";
     }

} 

    catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }


}

//Update
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
  try {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE tbl_pelanggan SET  nama_penuh = : name, nama_pengguna = :nama, katalaluan = :password, alamat_pelanggan = :alamat, email_pelanggan = :email, notel_pelanggan = :notel, img = :img
      WHERE pelanggan_id = :pid");

    $stmt->bindParam(':pid', $pid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':nama', $nama, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':alamat', $alamat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':notel', $notel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':img', $img, PDO::PARAM_STR);


    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $nama = $_POST['nama'];
    $pass = md5($_POST['password']);
    $repass = md5($_POST['repassword']);
    $alamat = $_POST['alamat'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $notel = $_POST['notel'];
    $img = $_POST['img'];


    if($pass == $repass)   {
    echo "<script>alert('Data anda berjaya dikemas kini. Terima kasih! ')</script>";     
    $stmt->execute();
     header("Location: profil.php");
     }

    if($pass !== $repass) {
       echo "<script>alert('Pastikan katalaluan dan taip semula katalaluan adalah sama!')</script>";
     }
  }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }


}

//Delete
if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {

  try {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM tbl_pelanggan where pelanggan_id = :pid");

    $stmt->bindParam(':pid', $pid, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $pid = $_GET['delete'];

    $stmt->execute();

    header("Location: mainpelanggan.php");
    }

  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
      echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}

//Edit
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {

  try {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_pelanggan where pelanggan_id = :pid");

    $stmt->bindParam(':pid', $pid, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $pid = $_GET['edit'];

    $stmt->execute();

    $editrow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
      echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}

  $conn = null;

?>
```

How can I solve it? Thank you for your time and answer

Comment: Which SQL statement fails? Is it the insert or the update?

Comment: in your update statement your have `nama_penuh = : name` , notice the extra space

Comment: Hints: `: name` should be `:name` and initialize your variables before `bindParam()` call.

Comment: ohh.. i didnt realize that mistake. tq so much for helping me